# Need help for password validator with complex conditions

Tags: python, passwords

I'm just starting out in python and I'm trying to build a simple python validation for the password. I want the password to contain 2 upper case letters, 2 lowercase letters and 2 special characters. The password must be a minimum length of 10. Here's what I have so far. the code doesn't give me any errors but I cannot get a good outcome. Your help would be much appreciated so I can understand what I'm doing wrong here.

```
def motdepasse(motdepasse):
majuscule = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVXYZ'
minuscule = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvxyz'
char = '[@_!#$%^&*()<>?/\|}{~:]'

while True:
    motdepasse = input("Entrez un mot de passe (Doit contenir 10 caractères avec 2 majuscules, 2 minuscules et 2 caractères spéciaux): ")
    valid = 0

    if len(motdepasse) < 10:
        print("Entrez un mot de passe valide!")

        continue

    elif not (motdepasse.find(majuscule)) >= 2  :
        print("Entrez un mot de passe valide!")

        continue

    elif not (motdepasse.find(minuscule)) >= 2:
        print("Entrez un mot de passe valide!")

        continue

    elif not (motdepasse.find(char)) >= 2 :
        print("Entrez un mot de passe valide!")

        continue

    else:
        valid = True
        break
if valid == 0:
    print("Mot de passe valide")
```

Comment: Please include what result you are expecting and what result you are getting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.find)

> **string.find(s, sub[, start[, end]]**
>
> ---
>
> Return the lowest index in s where the substring sub is found such that sub is wholly contained in s[start:end]. Return -1 on failure. Defaults for start and end and interpretation of negative values is the same as for slices.

Making it the wrong tool for the job.

You're checking if your whole `majuscule`, `minuscule` and `char` strings are in password and returning what index they're at.
What you'd want to do instead is to iterate over the characters and count matches in the password string. Something like this should do

```
majuscule = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVXYZ'
minuscule = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvxyz'
char = '[@_!#$%^&*()<>?/\|}{~:]'

while True:
    motdepasse = input("Entrez un mot de passe (Doit contenir 10 caractères avec 2 majuscules, 2 minuscules et 2 caractères spéciaux): ")
    valid = 0

    if len(motdepasse) < 10:
        print("Invalid Length")
        continue

    elif not len([x for x in motdepasse if x in majuscule]) >= 2:
        print("No Caps")
        continue

    elif not len([x for x in motdepasse if x in minuscule]) >= 2:
        print("Invalid lowercase")
        continue

    elif not len([x for x in motdepasse if x in char]) >= 2 :
        print("Invalid specials")
        continue

    else:
        valid = True
        break
if valid == 0:
    print("Mot de passe valide")
```

Output:

```
λ python run.py
Entrez un mot de passe (Doit contenir 10 caractères avec 2 majuscules, 2 minuscules et 2 caractères spéciaux): Stack
Invalid Length
Entrez un mot de passe (Doit contenir 10 caractères avec 2 majuscules, 2 minuscules et 2 caractères spéciaux): stackoverflow
No Caps
Entrez un mot de passe (Doit contenir 10 caractères avec 2 majuscules, 2 minuscules et 2 caractères spéciaux): StackOverflow
Invalid specials
Entrez un mot de passe (Doit contenir 10 caractères avec 2 majuscules, 2 minuscules et 2 caractères spéciaux): Stack@Overflow!
```

Comment: Thank you for you response and explaining it to me. I get what I was doing wrong but I I'm still unable to implement my conditions for my password to work correctly. I tried your code and tweaking it a bit and I still can't get it to work properly. Your code returned a few errors on line 15. My tweeks got it to work but isn't giving me the good returns. Entering a correct password still asks me to enter the correct amount of uppercase lowercase and special characters.

Comment: Code is running fine on my end. What errors did you get?

Comment: The code didn't read one of my variables correctly. I retyped the code making sure everything was in order and it worked perfectly. Thank you again for your help and your explanation.